# "Did you mean" suggestions is not working properly for sharepoint online site

Tags: search, sharepoint

"Did you mean" suggestions in sharepoint online site is not working properly for some search terms and for some it is working fine as per below screenshot.

Questions:

Why it is not working for search terms “Yammer, practitioner privileges”
How does this suggestions work ?[In this screenshot when we search for yammer word(correct spelling) then also search give did you mean suggestion as"Did you mean yammerss" (which is wrong spelling of yammer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhuif.png)

[Here also for priviledes it should give privileges in did you mean but not working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfsd2.png)